# Big O Complexity for nested loop

Tags: java, big-o, computer-science

```
for (i = 0; i < 2*n; i += 2) 
{
  for (j=n; j > i; j--)
    //some code that yields O(1)
}
```

I thought the above would yield `n*log(n)` but I've seen another source say that it is really is `n^2` complexity for big Oh.
Please explain to me which it is and how i could approach problems like this in the future.

Comment: It might help to know that the sum of integers from 1 to n is equal to `n*(n+1)/2`, which is clearly `O(n^2)`.

Comment: its o(n^2), total cycles would need to reduce by a multiplicative factor, say 1/2, each iteration for it to be o(n log n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Big O is for Upper Bound, so N * N will always be <= N^2, resulting in O(N*2). Answer is right

Comment: Since the increment is not 1 in the outer loop, this is not true since there are  not N steps but rather N/2

Comment: Check the outer loop again. 2N in steps of 2 will equate to?

Comment: Oh, i missed that. Thanks.
however, if it was just i<n would it be n log n?

Comment: Still it would be N^2 as Big O as I mentioned in my answer represents UPPER BOUND of the function

Comment: Dividing the number of steps by 2 (or any constant factor) still gives you the same Big O.

Answer (score 5):

You have a loop that depends on `n` and inside that loop you have another loop that also depends on `n`, thus the resulting O is `O(n*n)` i.e. `O(n^2)`.

Big O only provides an *upper bound* on the *growth rate* of an algorithm. Thus all constant factors are discarded.

Comment: This. Discarding constant factors is a much better way to explain it.